# Why do MongoDB views not support MapReduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, view

I am developing a database with MongoDB and would like to treat views as read-only collections. Particularly, I would really like to run map-reduce functions on a view. So my questions include:

- Why do views not support map-reduce?
- Are there plans to give map-reduce functionality to views in the future?
- Is there a workaround that would allow me to run map-reduce on query results?

Comment: Are you using an aggregate pipeline?

Comment: I believe I am (for the creation of the view). I use the $match operator. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Map and reduce are both available in the aggregate pipeline: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/ https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/

Comment: You can use them as steps in the pipeline db.createView(‘view_name’,’source’,[pipeline])

Answer (score 0):

Views in MongoDB are not materialized so querying a view involves running the aggregation pipeline that you specified when you defined the view.  This means that you can do further aggregations on the view via aggregation pipeline, but you cannot use map/reduce which cannot run aggregation stages as part of its execution.

Most things that you can do with map/reduce in MongoDB can be done with aggregation pipeline (though certainly not all).  I would recommend seeing how far you can get using purely aggregation rather than map-reduce.